# What's the difference between cache.period and cache.cachecontrol.max-age?

Tags: spring-boot

In the list of Spring Boot [common application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html), there are two caching duration related entries that sound similar to me:

**spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.max-age:**

`Maximum time the response should be cached, in seconds if no duration suffix is not specified.`

**spring.resources.cache.period:**

`Cache period for the resources served by the resource handler. If a duration suffix is not specified, seconds will be used.`

In Spring Boot 1.x with **cache.period** defined, I could swear that my static resources were getting served with a cache-control header, and a max-age set to the duration provided.

In Spring Boot 2.x, I started noticing that there was no cache-control header being applied to my static resources anymore. I then replaced it with **cache.cachecontrol.max-age** and I now see the cache-control/max-age header appearing as expected.

What's the difference between these two items, and why does there appear to have been a change in behavior from 1.x to 2.x? Is this just a bug that I should log, or is there a subtle difference between the two that I'm just not understanding?

Comment: The problem in Spring Boot 2.x of **cache.period** has been resolved in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16488

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Molham in the comments -- closing this as answered. It appears this was a bug, and was resolved.

Issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16488

Fixing commit: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/94a9748ce0764cc52271385402e43d93c2232fa8